# Normal numbers in base 2 are meager (of the first category).

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

What is a simple proof that the set of normal numbers in base 2 in $[0,1]$ is of the first category (meager)?

> **Definition 1**. A set is called *meager* or of the *first category* if it is the countable union of nowhere dense sets.
>
> **Definition 2**. A number $x=.x_1x_2x_3...$ written in its binary expansion is called *normal* in base 2 if
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: What kind of union does the definition of meager use? E.g. finitely many sets in the union?

Comment: Sorry, that was missing indeed.

Answer (score 6):

For any natural number $n$, there is a dense open set $G_n$ of points $x\in[0,1]$ satisfying the following condition: For some $k\geq n$, the binary expansion of $x$ has only 0's from position $k$ to position $2^k$.  ($G_n$ doesn't contain *all* such points $x$; some endpoints have to be removed to make $G_n$ open.)  The complement of $G_n$ is then nowhere dense, and so the complement of $\bigcap_nG_n$ is of first category.  But that complement contains all normal numbers in base 2.

Comment: I don't get very well the part where I should remove some points to make it open, Which ones?. How can I write this formally? (Thanks in advance)

Comment: @MauricioGTec and Andreas Blass Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340514/normal-numbers-are-meager

Comment: @MauricioGTec The points to remove are the rational numbers whose denominators are powers of 2.  (Each of these has two binary expansions, one ending in all zeros from some point on, and one ending in all ones from some point on.)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti In the question at your link, you seem to fix, for each $n$, a certain $k$ and then define $G_n$ in terms of that $k$.  Contrast that with my definition here, which existentially quantifies $k$ ("For some $k\geq n,\dots$") rather than fixing it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you. In case I would need a reference of the above result, do you have one? I see everyone is quoting Oxtoby's book, but I cannot find exactly where it is

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I don't have easy access to references at the moment, so I can't give you  specific citation.  It may be that this result is too straightforward to be explained explicitly in the literature.

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway