# The set of $e \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$ such that $e_1+\cdots+e_n\neq o(n)$

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Endow the space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$ of sequences $(e_1,e_2,\ldots)$ with the product topology (of the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$), which is completely metrizable. Modulo my mistakes, it has been proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340514/normal-numbers-are-meager) that the following set is meager:
$$
\left\{(e_1,e_2,\ldots) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}: \liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac{e_1+\cdots+e_n}{n}>0\right\}.
$$

Here we ask a stronger question (which probably has a negative answer):

> **Question.** Is the following set meager?
>   $$
> \left\{(e_1,e_2,\ldots) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}: \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{e_1+\cdots+e_n}{n}>0\right\}
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipping all the digits is a homeomorphism, so your first statement shows that
$$\left\{(e_1,e_2,\ldots) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}: \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{e_1+\cdots+e_n}{n}<1\right\}$$
is meagre, so its complement is comeagre, and you're asking about an even bigger set.